# The boundary of the standard n-cube (Spivak)

Tags: differential-geometry

Please read the following definition of the boundary of the standard $n$-cube. It comes from Spivak's book.
[CALCULUS ON MANIFOLDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KMiZ.png)
I feel confused about the range of the index $i$. What if $i$ is taken to be $n$ or $1$? In this case, is it reasonable to talk about
$$I_{(i,0)}^n(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1})=I^n(x^1,\ldots,x^{i-1},0,x^i,\ldots,x^{n-1})?$$
As revealed above, the symbol $I_{(i,0)}^n(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1})$ indicates that $0$ is to be plugged in between the $(i-1)$-th entry and the $i$-th entry. Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Is it a typo? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $I(0,x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1})$ and $I(x^1,\ldots,x^{n-1},0)$?